# Meteor.startup on the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

When using the following code on the client side, why is the variable `init` in `if(init)` evaluated to be `true` even though it comes before `init = true` and no new documents are added to the `Orders` collection? This results in the `query.observe` returning all documents returned by the query, not just newly added ones.

This behavior is not observed on the server side, which only executes the `console.log` when new documents are added.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    var init = false
    var query = Orders.find()
    var handle = query.observe({
        added: function (doc) {
            if(init)
                console.log(doc)
        }
    });

    init = true

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because everything is *synchronous on the server* whereas everything is *asynchronous on the client*.

`init=true` will be set after the `query.observe` operation is finished, but on the client it could be set before this as `init` would be set to `true` almost as immediately as the observe handle is run.

You would have to use a different kind of behavior to make it work in the way you expect on the client.

Maybe use something that gets the timestamp after a subscription is complete, and then only continue if the current timestamp is higher:

```
Meteor.subscribe("yourdocs", function() {
    Session.set("yourdocs_finishtime", new Date().getTime());
});
```

Then your added handle:

```
added: function (doc) {
    var subtime = Session.get("yourdocs_finishtime");
    if(subtime && (subtime < new Date().getTime()))
        console.log(doc);
}
```